# Add a third monitor to Asus K513E

Tags: monitors, video-adapters

My laptop is an Asus K513E with the i7-1165G7, 16Gb of ram and the Nvidia MX330. It has 3 normal USB and 1 USB type c. I assumed that I could connect a third screen via USB type c, so I bought two monitors. The first one was easy to connect to the HDMI, but the second one does not work.

I got a USB-c to HDMI adapter. I later found out that the USB type C port is not designed to output a display, so it doesn't work. I found an other adapter USB to USB-c, to connect the screen to a regular USB port, but doesn't work, Windows doesn't recognize the third screen.

Is there any other piece of hardware that will let me connect a third monitor even thou my computer doesn't seem to support it?

Answer (score 1):

USB-C to HDMI will only work when the USB-C supports DP mode or Thunderbolt (3 or 4), and only then, so your USB-C trial was not worth it. If you want to mirror the two external displays, you can get an HDMI splitter like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Splitter-LinkS-Amplifier-Source-Displays/dp/B0732MD43P/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0732MD43P)